# Scroll bar to nothing - how can I make my page shorter?

Tags: html, css

We have to support the last two revisions of IE, Chrome and Firefox and I have a feeling this isn't possible with IE 7/8, but perhaps I'm missing something

I have a footer that is moved up behind a content area by -280px.  This content area is moved up over a header area by -230px.  As a result I have a blank area at the bottom of my page of approx 320px.  I can fill this and make it appear to be the bottom end of the gradient, but I'd really rather just cut it out, so there's no scroll bar to nothing.

In the example code below -

```
<div id = "page">
    <div id = "topbar">
    </div>
    <div id = "header">
    </div>
    <div id = "content">
    </div>
</div>
<div id = "footer">
    I AM THA FOOTAH<br/> So much cooler than the header these days
</div>
body
{
/*  background-color: #040e22; */
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

div
{
    display: block;
}


#page
{
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;   
    position: relative;
}

#topbar
{
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #112247;
    color: white;
    position: static;
}

#header
{
    background-color: navy;
    color: yellow;
    height: 240px;
    position: relative;
}

#content
{
    min-height: 280px;
    background-color: green;
    width: 480px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: -230px;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 2000px;

}

#footer
{
    /*background: url("footerGradient.png") repeat-x 50% 0%;*/
    background-color: navy;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 60px;
    height: 220px;
    top: -280px;
    position: relative;
}


.inner
{
    width: 940px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

how do I get rid of the white under the navy footer?

Comment: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change in your #footer from `top: -280px` to `margin-top: -280px` voila!

position relative will move the element relatively to its original location but will perserve its space thus rendering empty area, negative margin will move your element including its bounding space and will do what you need.

Comment: You're my hero!  I knew it was either going to be simple or impossible.

Comment: cheers - keep it in mind for the future, positioning with margins is often a good alternative to relative positioning especially when we are speaking of negative values :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the footer position from relative to static like so:

```
#footer
{
    /*background: url("footerGradient.png") repeat-x 50% 0%;*/
    background-color: navy;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 60px;
    height: 220px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this [sticky footer page](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)-- you can modify that technique by NOT making the height of the footer and the negative margin of the previous element the same; you would want the negative margin to be greater.